# Aligning and cropping same scene images

Tags: python, linux, opencv, imagemagick

Hello I have different images taken using exposure bracketing (same scene different exposures), I need to align the images and crop each one of them in order for them to be matching exactly. (since there was camera shake when these images were taken)

I don't want to merge them, i just want to cut, rotate, or scale ..etc each one in order for them to be exactly aligned, then save them. I would have added a code sample if i knew how i could do this. but i have no idea. I'm new to opencv.

Here's an example:

[image]

Here's a real example of a sample : (this sample has a huge misalignment, most of the samples need just small adjustments because of shaking unlike this one)

[image]

What i need is to crop each one of the images to make them identical (keep only the shared area)

Thank you !

Comment: Are your images representative? Aligning simple black shapes on a white background is not the same as aligning real-world photos...

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you for your quick response, i have updated the question and added more information.

Comment: Is it for the coding challenge or for the result? A free program like "Hugin" can do this (`Feature matching: align image stack`). There is even an `align_image_stack` script to automate this function. If you want to code this, keep in mind that you real problem is that the axis of the lens has changed, so the projection of the outside world on your sensor is not the same, and this is more complex than scale/rotate/shift. And you have to take in account lens distortion...

Comment: @xenoid it is not for a coding challenge. i'm trying to teach a neural network how to do exposure fusion (https://mericam.github.io/exposure_fusion/index.html) the input should be different exposures (3 images) of exactly the same scene. and the output (1 image) should be a more detailed better representation of the scene

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On this answer I describe an approach to achieve **Image Alignment** which consists on using the *euclidean model* to transform *image 1* (on the left) and *image 3* (on the right) according to *image 2*, the center image.

[image]

[image]

However, I would like to quickly point out that the images shared are very challenging: not only there's a big difference in contrast but they also have a significant difference in **translation**, **scale**, **rotation**, and maybe even a little bit of **shearing**. The fact that they were posted as very low resolution also doesn't help.

Anyway, I pointed out their differences in terms of **2D transformations** because that's something you always need to keep in mind when selecting the appropriate *model* to perform image alignment. [This nice picture is from a tutorial that describes the models in greater detail](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/):

[image]

The approach consists on the following steps:

- Use Enhanced Correlation Coefficient (ECC) algorithm to perform image alignment using the euclidean model between images 2 and 1;
- The returned transformation matrix is then used to transform image 1 with the help of `cv2.warpAffine()` and calculate the approximate rectangular area of the transformation in image 1;
- Repeat the same steps to transform image 3: use Enhanced Correlation Coefficient (ECC) algorithm to perform image alignment using the euclidean model between images 2 and 3;
- The returned transformation matrix is then used to transform image 3 with the help of `cv2.warpAffine()` and calculate the approximate rectangular area of the transformation.
- The result of these operations are the aligned images and can be seen on the image below. The green rectangles show the area of transformation:

[image]

- The red rectangle in the center image, the reference image used to create the model for the transformations, is the intersection between the areas on images 1 and 3 and can be seen as being the common area between all 3 images.
- The red rectangle can then be used to crop images 1, 2, and 3 and give that nice look of image alignment. Notice how the terrain and the sky on all these images appear to be perfectly aligned with each other:

[image]

It's interesting to notice the cost of this approach: because image 1 didn't capture all those terrain features that can be easily seen on images 2 and 3, the final result is that images 2 and 3 end up loosing that part of the terrain. Thus, all the images show the exact same area of the photo.

**Python source code**:

```
###
# reference:
#   https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/
###
import numpy as np
import cv2

# internalRect: returns the intersection between two rectangles
#
#  p1 ---------------- p2
#   |                  |
#   |                  |
#   |                  |
#  p4 ---------------- p3
def internalRect(r1, r2):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    w = 2
    h = 3

    rect1_pt1 = [       r1[x], r1[y]       ]
    rect1_pt2 = [ r1[x]+r1[w], r1[y]       ]
    rect1_pt3 = [ r1[x]+r1[w], r1[y]+r1[h] ]
    rect1_pt4 = [       r1[x], r1[y]+r1[h] ]

    rect2_pt1 = [       r2[x], r2[y]       ]
    rect2_pt2 = [ r2[x]+r2[w], r2[y]       ]
    rect2_pt3 = [ r2[x]+r2[w], r2[y]+r2[h] ]
    rect2_pt4 = [       r2[x], r2[y]+r2[h] ]

    int_pt1   = [ max(rect1_pt1[x], rect2_pt1[x]), max(rect1_pt1[y], rect2_pt1[y]) ]
    int_pt2   = [ min(rect1_pt2[x], rect2_pt2[x]), max(rect1_pt2[y], rect2_pt2[y]) ]
    int_pt3   = [ min(rect1_pt3[x], rect2_pt3[x]), min(rect1_pt3[y], rect2_pt3[y]) ]
    int_pt4   = [ max(rect1_pt4[x], rect2_pt4[x]), min(rect1_pt4[y], rect2_pt4[y]) ]

    rect =  [ int_pt1[x], int_pt1[y], int_pt2[x]-int_pt1[x], int_pt4[y]-int_pt1[y] ]
    return rect


# align_image: use src1 as the reference image to transform src2
def align_image(src1, src2, warp_mode=cv2.MOTION_TRANSLATION):
    # convert images to grayscale
    img1_gray = cv2.cvtColor(src1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(src2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # define 2x3 or 3x3 matrices and initialize it to a identity matrix
    if warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY:
        warp_matrix = np.eye(3, 3, dtype=np.float32)
    else:
        warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)

    # number of iterations:
    num_iters = 1000

    # specify the threshold of the increment in the correlation coefficient between two iterations
    termination_eps = 1e-8    

    # Define termination criteria
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, num_iters,  termination_eps)

    print('findTransformECC() may take a while...')

    # perform ECC: use the selected model to calculate the transformation required to align src2 with src1. The resulting transformation matrix is stored in warp_matrix:
    (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(img1_gray, img2_gray, warp_matrix, warp_mode, criteria, inputMask=None, gaussFiltSize=1)

    if (warp_mode == cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY):
        img2_aligned = cv2.warpPerspective(src2, warp_matrix, (src1.shape[1], src1.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)
    else :
        # use warpAffine() for: translation, euclidean and affine models
        img2_aligned = cv2.warpAffine(src2, warp_matrix, (src1.shape[1], src1.shape[0]), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=0)

    #print('warp_matrix shape', warp_matrix.shape, 'data=\n', warp_matrix)
    #print(warp_matrix, warp_matrix)

    # compute the cropping area to remove the black bars from the transformed image
    x = 0
    y = 0
    w = src1.shape[1]
    h = src1.shape[0]

    if (warp_matrix[0][2] < 0):
        x = warp_matrix[0][2] * -1
        w -= x

    if (warp_matrix[1][2] < 0):
        y = warp_matrix[1][2] * -1
        h -= y

    if (warp_matrix[1][2] > 0):
        h -= warp_matrix[1][2]
    
    matchArea = [ int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h) ]
  
    #print('src1 w=', src1.shape[1], 'h=', src1.shape[0])
    #print('matchedRect=', matchArea[0], ',', matchArea[1], '@', matchArea[2], 'x', matchArea[3], '\n')
    return img2_aligned, matchArea


##########################################################################################


img1 = cv2.imread("img1.png")
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.png")
img3 = cv2.imread("img3.png")

# TODO: adjust contrast on all input images

###
# resize images to be the same size as the smallest image for debug purposes
###
max_h = img1.shape[0]
max_h = max(max_h, img2.shape[0])
max_h = max(max_h, img3.shape[0])
max_w = img1.shape[1]
max_w = max(max_w, img2.shape[1])
max_w = max(max_w, img3.shape[1])
img1_padded = cv2.resize(img1, (max_w, max_h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img2_padded = cv2.resize(img2, (max_w, max_h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
img3_padded = cv2.resize(img3, (max_w, max_h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

# stack them horizontally for display
hStack = np.hstack((img1_padded, img2_padded))  # stack images side-by-side
input_stacked = np.hstack((hStack, img3_padded))      # stack images side-by-side
cv2.imwrite("input_stacked.jpg", input_stacked)
cv2.imshow("input_stacked", input_stacked)
cv2.waitKey(0)

###
# perform image alignment
###

# specify the motion model
warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN   # cv2.MOTION_TRANSLATION, cv2.MOTION_EUCLIDEAN, cv2.MOTION_AFFINE, cv2.MOTION_HOMOGRAPHY

# for testing purposes: img2 will be the reference image
img1_aligned, matchArea1 = align_image(img2, img1, warp_mode)
img1_aligned_cpy = img1_aligned.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img1_aligned_cpy, (matchArea1[0], matchArea1[1]),  (matchArea1[0]+matchArea1[2], matchArea1[1]+matchArea1[3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("img1_aligned.jpg", img1_aligned_cpy)

print('\n###############################################\n')

# for testing purposes: img2 will be the reference image again
img3_aligned, matchArea3 = align_image(img2, img3, warp_mode)
img3_aligned_cpy = img3_aligned.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img3_aligned_cpy, (matchArea3[0], matchArea3[1]),  (matchArea3[0]+matchArea3[2], matchArea3[1]+matchArea3[3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("img3_aligned.jpg", img3_aligned_cpy)

# compute the crop area in the reference image and draw a red rectangle
cropRect = internalRect(matchArea1, matchArea3)
print('cropRect=', cropRect[0], ',', cropRect[1], '@', cropRect[2], 'x', cropRect[3], '\n')

img2_eq_cpy = img2.copy()
cv2.rectangle(img2_eq_cpy, (cropRect[0], cropRect[1]),  (cropRect[0]+cropRect[2], cropRect[1]+cropRect[3]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imwrite("img2_eq.jpg", img2_eq_cpy)

# stack results horizontally for display
res_hStack = np.hstack((img1_aligned_cpy, img2_eq_cpy))                 # stack images side-by-side
aligned_stacked = np.hstack((res_hStack, img3_aligned_cpy))             # stack images side-by-side
cv2.imwrite("aligned_stacked.jpg", aligned_stacked)
cv2.imshow("aligned_stacked", aligned_stacked)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print('\n###############################################\n')

# crop images to the smallest internal area between them
img1_aligned_cropped = img1_aligned[cropRect[1] : cropRect[1]+cropRect[3], cropRect[0] : cropRect[0]+cropRect[2]]
img3_aligned_cropped = img3_aligned[cropRect[1] : cropRect[1]+cropRect[3], cropRect[0] : cropRect[0]+cropRect[2]]
img2_eq_cropped      =         img2[cropRect[1] : cropRect[1]+cropRect[3], cropRect[0] : cropRect[0]+cropRect[2]]

cropped_hStack = np.hstack((img1_aligned_cropped, img2_eq_cropped))     # stack images side-by-side
cropped_stacked = np.hstack((cropped_hStack, img3_aligned_cropped))     # stack images side-by-side
cv2.imwrite("cropped_stacked.jpg", cropped_stacked)
cv2.imshow("cropped_stacked", cropped_stacked)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, THANK YOU.